# SED: How to insert string to the beginning of the last line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, insert

How to insert string to the beginning of the last line?

I want to add a time stamp to a text file which contains multiple lines

```
var1 = `date`

LINE1
LINE2
LINE3
...
(INSERT var1 here) LASTLINE
```

`sed 's/^/test line /g' textfile` inserts characters to the beginning of every line but how can I specifically modify the last line only?

Thanks

Going forward:
`sed '$s/^/sample text /' textfile` works, but only when inserting regular strings. If I try

```
var1 = "sample text"
```

and use substition, here are the problems I encounter

1. using single quotes in sed does not expand variables, so sed '$s/^/$var1/' textfile will insert the string $var1 into the beginning of the last line.
2. To enable variable substitution I tried using double quotes. It works when I specify the exact line number. something like:

   sed "5s/^/$var1/" textfile

But when I try `sed "$s/^/$var1" text file`, it returns an error:

**sed: -e expression #1, char 5: extra characters after command**

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
sed '$s/^/test line /' textfile
```

`$` indicates last line. Similarly, you can insert into a any specific line by putting the line number in place of `$`

Comment: Moving forward, I am trying to insert a variable containing the current date-time. The var1=`date` is used, echo $var1 prints the correct output, but when I use it for substitution, sed '$s/^/${var1} /' textfile, I am getting the output ${var1} LAST LINE, it wont perform the substitution.. How to fix this please?

Comment: It works for regular strings but it returns an error when substituing from a variable

Answer (score 1):

```
But when I try sed "$s/^/$var1" text file, it returns an error:
```

It returns an error because the *shell* attempts to expand `$s` since you've used double quotes.  You need to *escape* the `$` in `$s`.

```
sed "\$s/^/$var1/" filename
```

Comment: or simply add a space between **$** and **s**. `sed "$ s/^/$Var1/"` YourFile

Answer (score 0):

`sed`should be the best tool, but `awk` can do this too:

```
awk '{a[++t]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<t;i++) print a[i];print v$0}' v="$var1" file
```

It will insert value of `var1` in front of last line

---

Another variation

```
awk 'NR==f {$0=v$0}1' v="$var1" f=$(wc -l file)
```

PS you do not need to specify file after `awk`, not sure why.  If you do so, it reads it double.

Answer (score 0):

This command would work for you:

```
sed -i "5s/^/$var1 /" text file
```

Comment: The file I will be using does not have a fixed number of lines I need sed to insert specifically on the last line regardless of hos many lines it currently has. sed "$ s/^/$Var1/" file.txt works.Thanks